# Why can't Xcode find the info.plist in this Ionic app?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, info.plist

I have not been able to get around this error. Not sure why it's throwing this. I have other similar Ionic apps that build just fine. I don't see any differences and haven't been able to find a resolution online. Below is the error:

> Info.plist Utility Error Group
>
> error: could not read data from
> '.../brt-portal/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Cordova/Info.plist':
> The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such
> file.

Here is my Ionic and Xcode info for the project

```
Ionic:
    
Ionic CLI          : 6.10.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2 
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
    
Cordova:
    
Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Cordova Platforms : ios 4.5.5 
Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (22 plugins total)
    
Utility:
    
cordova-res (update available: 0.15.1) : 0.9.0
native-run        : 1.0.0
    
System:
    
ios-deploy : 1.10.0
ios-sim    : 6.1.3
NodeJS     : v13.13.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.13.0_1/bin/node)
npm        : 6.14.2
OS         : macOS Catalina
Xcode      : Xcode 11.5 Build version 11E608c
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's related to modern build system. Namely, XCode 10 uses the modern build system by default, whereas Cordova 4.5.5 does not.

What you could do is either to update to `cordova-ios` 5.0+ (`platform remove` and `platform add` to be sure everything is rebuilt correctly).

Or force XCode to use Legacy build system via: `ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0`, or create a `build.json` in your project root with:

```
{  
"ios": {
    "debug": {
      "buildFlag": [
        "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
      ]
    },
    "release": {
      "buildFlag": [
        "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Or open your XCode workspace and click `File -> Workspace Settings -> Build System: Legacy Build System`

Comment: I am using the Legacy build system, I should have stated that above.